# Doubts about interpretation of the curves of effective potential energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, angular-momentum, potential, potential-energy

[image: Graph]

The image shows a graph of the effective potential energy. Where,$K=-Gm_{1}m_{2}$ and $L$ is the angular momentum.

The graph of the effective potential energy that can be seen in this publication was created to determine the nature of the possible orbits corresponding to the law of forces inversely proportional to the square of the distance.
I see that the graph corresponds to different values of $K$ and $L$.
For a repulsion force $(K> 0)$, why are only positive total energies possible? And why will only unlimited orbits be possible? In the absence of force $(K = 0)$ I can't interpret what happens. If the force is attractive $(K <0)$ with $L ≠ 0$, will the movement be unlimited? If so, what is the explanation for this?
In definitely I can't understand how I should interpret the graph that I published and what function the angular momentum has in this curves. Why do the curves change for different angular momentum values?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential

Comment: These curves, their dependence on $r$ and corresponding orbits come from a very specific topic of classical mechanics named central force motion. It may be better for you to check a textbook (like Marion's Classical Dynamics).